# finding the value of an unfair coin toss

Tags: probability, statistics

A gambler tosses an unfair coin n times, the probability of heads were 0.7 each time. The probability of 5

heads in the n tosses is 21 times as great as the probability of
4 heads. What would the value of n be?

not sure if my work is correct:

Let X be the number of heads

X follows Binomial distribution with n and p=0.7

using the probability mass function of a Binomial distribution

given p(x=5)=21 *p(x=4)

n-4=45

n=49

Answer : n= 49

Comment: Yes your answer is correct

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It might benefit from showing how you got $n-4=45$.  I suspect you used $21\times 5 \times \frac{0.3}{0.7}$ but you could explain why that is a sensible thing to do.

Comment: Yes. in R, `pbinom(5,49,.7)` returns $3.156092e-18$ and  `21*dbinom(4,49,.7)` also returns $3.156092e-18.$